# Need to Reference multiple sheets with IF(OR(AND( imbeded

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, embedded

I need to reference 3 sheets, "Shipping", "Equipment", and "Inventory", where Column A in Shipping and Column A in Equipment both refer to the Location Number, and Equipment Type is designated by text and counted in a pivot table in "Inventory". There are multiple types of equipment associated with each location number, and some Location Numbers have not been associated yet.

In plain English, I am trying to say "IF Location Number in Shipping Matches Location Number in Equipment AND the Equipment type Matches Inventory A9 Or Equipment type matches Inventory A8, Return the Tracking Number in Column K, Otherwise return a blank value".

My formula is

```
=IF(AND(Equipment!A:A=Shipping!A2,OR(Equipment!C:C=Inentory!A8,Equipment!C:C=Inentory!A9)),Equipment!K:K,"").
```

While I know there is correct value to return, and logically, this should work, I'm getting the false value return anyway, so I know there is an intricacy that I am missing. Any help?

Comment: Hmm. Did you mean to have `Inentory` (spelling mistake, twice) in your formula? Should it be `Inventory`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues here.

Generally excel formulas don't handle arrays as inputs (if you just hit enter) so your formula is only comparing the first cell of your ranges.

If you do enter an array formula using **ctrl+shift+enter** it will compare against the full range but your **or** and **and** functions will simplify that down to a single true/false for the entire range (not for each row individually).

So using an array formula you could use something like this: but note that array formulas can get very slow if you are using whole column arrays (since they each contain ~1M cells so you are much better actually defining the range.

```
=index(Equipment!K:K,
    match(Shipping!A2,
        if(((Equipment!C:C=Inentory!A8)+(Equipment!C:C=Inentory!A9))>0,Equipment!A:A,0)
    ,0)
)
```